# Objects in foreach Loop are Passed by Reference Without "&"

Tags: php, loops, object, foreach, pass-by-reference

It was my understanding for a while that `foreach` clones the individual objects in its iterations, and I had used `&` to iterate by reference. However, in my latest machine which runs PHP 5.5.10, I'm able to omit `&` and still update the original object. I don't see anything in the release notes. Am I misunderstanding something?

```
foreach ($items as $item) {    // No "&"
    $item->setData('123');    // Updates the respective object in $items
    // Checked object ID hash, and they're the same with or without "&"
}
```

PHP Change Log: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP paradigm is that objects (and resources) are *always* references, while other types (base types or arrays) are copied, so the `&` operator has no effect on objects (and is meaningless on resources since only "special functions" i.e. external library modules can take them as parameters), but allows to pass variables of other types by reference.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP objects are always passed by reference. How it work? Objects has identifier which is passed, we can call this *handle*. So if you:

```
$a = new A();
$b = $a;
$b->foo = 2;
echo $a->foo;
```

return value will be `2`. Why? Because the *handle* of the object is copied to `$b` and they both - `$a` and `$b` - point to the same object. We can term this as a reference, but it isn't reference meaning in strict way, but behaviour of this implementation is similar to reference. So you do not need any use of references because PHP make it for you by default.

Read the [`OOP references documentation`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Comment: Everything is passed by value in PHP if it's without `&`, and passed by reference with `&`. But it is irrelevant because there is no passing here.

Comment: In objects it isn't reference, it's identifier to object, reference meaning the same object in memory but in PHP, is not pointer to memory it's pointer to identifier. Why downvote?

Comment: You said "objects are always passed by reference", which is completely incorrect. 1) "Objects" are not values in PHP5 and cannot be "passed". 2) *Everything* is passed by value if the parameter has no `&`, and passed by reference if the parameter has `&`. The type that the value may have is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach assigns each element of the array to the given variable, as in simple assignment, with `=`, which copies the value of the element to the variable. This is always true regardless of what type the value happens to have. (Only if you do `as &$item` will it be a reference.)

`$item` is not "an object". `$item` is an object reference, basically a pointer to an object. In PHP 5, you cannot have a variable whose value "is an object" -- when you do `new something()`, you get a reference to an object; when you access a field or method with `->`, the left side must be a reference to an object. Basically, you always deal with references to objects, never objects themselves.

Two object references can point to the same object, and if you modify an object by calling a method on it using one object reference, the result is visible through another object reference that points to the same object.